# fabric.js: Does resizing image using Image.set() reduce image quality?

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

I need to reduce the height/width of an image before adding to a Canvas. We are using fabric.js.

When the image is resized using the [image.set()](http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.Object.html#set) function shown below, does it degrade the image quality?

```
imgAdd.onload = function () {
var img = new fabric.Image(imgAdd);
var imgSizeObj = img.getOriginalSize();
var newImgSize = calculateAspectRatioFit(imgSizeObj.width, imgSizeObj.height, canvas.width, canvas.height);
if (imgSizeObj.width > canvas.width || imgSizeObj.height > canvas.height) {

    //Does img.set() preserve image resolution?
    img.set({
        width: newImgSize.width,
        height: newImgSize.height
    });
}

canvas.add(img);
}
```

The goal is to maintain image quality but automatically scale a large image to fit within the canvas.

Thank you,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it doesnt.
The image is stored in a property of the `object._element` and does not change unless you apply some filter over it.
Even in that situation a copy is stored in `object._originalElement`.

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following:

```
var scale = bef;
img.set({
    scaleX: scale,
    scaleY: scale
});
```

You can find more information on this here: https://github.com/kangax/fabric.js/issues/176